# mysql join query timing out on local machine

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have imported two csv files on my local machine as Table a and Table b,
Table a has 5.5 million records and each record has 116 column, Table b has 200 records and each record has 3 columns.

When I perform the below query i receive:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Columns `initial_user_code` and `user` are indexed. Can someone please help in optimising the below query or am I doing something completely wrong, the query works if I perform it on 100 thousand records.

```
UPDATE Table_A a
JOIN Table_b b ON a.initial_user_code = b.user
SET a.case_createdby = b.id
```

Comment: It's probably taking a lot of time, so try increasing net_read_timout and net_write_timeout server system variables.

Comment: "Chunking" is a way to avoid one hugely long query.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

Comment: @RickJames chunking resolved my issue, thank you!!!